# moment on DatePicker react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using the next React component:

```
<DatePicker
        selected = {this.state.startDate}
        onChange = {(d) => {console.log('date = ' + d); 
                    this.setState({startDate: d})}}
                    dateFormat="MMMM, DD, YYYY"
/>
```

it works fine if startDate is equal to moment() but I get error message if I execute

```
this.setState({startDate:   momdate});
```

where

```
var momdate = moment('2017-10-22').valueOf() / 1000;
```

and this instruction is executed at the

```
 componentDidMount()
```

react function. The error message is:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: e.clone is not a function
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/491) but it looks like `<DatePicker>` requires the state to be an object.

Instead of setting `momdate` to be calling `.valueOf()` try just doing `moment('2017-10-22')`